# jQuery Autocomplete Not Showing Results on Client-Side

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, flask, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My results don't get populated in the Autocomplete  powered by jQuery UI. I just see empty rows beneath my search bar and sometimes they don't even show up.

I do see my results in the console window as I type characters in the search field. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My client-side code is setup like this:

```
<input id="autocomplete" class="form-control input-lg" name="autocomplete" placeholder="Search an address" type="text">

$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.getJSON('{{url_for("getInfo")}}', {
      a: request.term,
    }, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      response(data.addresses);
    });
  },
  minLength: 3,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.item.value);
  }
});
```

I can see the results from the `console.log(data);` line. It returns an Object with an Array of 3 items inside it: `Object {addresses: Array[3]}`

My server-side code using Flask is set up like this:

```
@app.route('/getInfo', methods=['GET'])
def getInfo():
    address = request.args.get("a")
    addressCollection = myDB["addresses"]
    addressJSON = []

    for address in addressCollection.find({'Address': {'$regex':regex,'$options':'i'} },{"Address":1,"_id":0}).limit(3):
        addressJSON.append({"Address":address["Address"]})
    return jsonify(addresses=addressJSON)
```

The result looks like this:

```
{
  "addresses": [
    {
      "Address": "29 Valleyridge Rd",
    }, 
    {
      "Address": "29 Valleyview Dr", 
    }, 
    {
      "Address": "29 Valleystone Cr",
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI Autocomplete [source](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) requires an array of strings, or an array of objects having `label` and `value` properties. So you should transform your data accordingly. Your success callback should be something like:

```js
function(data) {
  var transformed = data.addresses.map(function(address) {
    return address.Address;
  });
  response(transformed);
}
```

Or

```js
function(data) {
  var transformed = data.addresses.map(function(address) {
    return {
      label: address.Address
    };
  });
  response(transformed);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. This solution works great.